# React + EmailJS is sending me tons of emails in onClick method

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to web development in general but I'm trying to create my own Contact page on my website and I'm having trouble.  I'm using React, Gatsby, and Emailjs.  I have my form set up so that the inputs are passed into the state onChange.  Then I have a "send message" button that should send an email using EmailJS using the tokens and the state vars.  **This does all work and the email sends successfully**, but it's sending dozens of emails.  I believe what's happening is it's calling sendEmail every time the state is set and the DOM re-renders, or basically once for each character that's input into the fields, but I don't know why.

Bonus points if you can help me figure out why pressing the send message button also sends me to a 404 /# route on my site.

```
import React from 'react'
import emailjs from 'emailjs-com

class Main extends React.Component {

  constructor(){
    super()
    this.state = {
      fromName:'',
      message:'',
      fromEmail:''
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div ...
      >
        ...

        <article>
          ...
          <form method="post" action="#">
            <div className="field half first">
              <label htmlFor="name">Name</label>
              <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value={this.state.fromName} onChange={e => this.setState({fromName: e.target.value})}/>
            </div>
            <div className="field half">
              <label htmlFor="email">Email</label>
              <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value={this.state.fromEmail} onChange={e => this.setState({fromEmail: e.target.value})}/>
            </div>
            <div className="field">
              <label htmlFor="message">Message</label>
              <textarea name="message" id="message" rows="4" value={this.state.message} onChange={e => this.setState({message: e.target.value})}
                placeholder = "..."></textarea>
            </div>
            <ul className="actions">
              <li>
                <input type="submit" value="Send Message" className="special" onClick={this.sendEmail()}/>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </form>
        </article>
      </div>
    )
  }

  sendEmail() {
    const serviceId='...'
    const templateId='...'
    const userId='...'
    emailjs.send(serviceId, templateId, this.state, userId)
  }

}

export default Main
```

Comment: It is. The issue is here `onClick={this.sendEmail()}` you are immediately invoking the callback each time the UI is rendered. It should be `onClick={this.sendEmail}` sans the parentheses. If you don't want the `form` element to take the default form action (involves reloading the page, or in your case, navigating to "/#") then don't make the input a "submit", i.e. change it to `type="button"` Voting to close as "Not reproducible or was caused by a typo". Cheers.

Comment: onClick={this.sendEmail}.

Comment: @DrewReese Thank you so much for the response.  When I just tried getting rid of the parentheses I'm now getting an error in the sendEmail function "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'state')"when pressing the send message button

Comment: Please add event as a parameter in your sendEmail function. Then inside send email call the  event.preventDefault() function @dulongj

Comment: Yeah, then I would suggest moving the submit handler to the form element instead of on an `onClick` of the input. `<form onSubmit={this.sendEmail}>...` and then in `sendEmail` receive the `onSubmit` event object and call `event.preventDefault()` to keep the form from taking the submit action.

Comment: True @DrewReese that's what I have done in the below answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you never followed the emailjs documentation well and you never prevented the default form action.
According to the emailjs documentation you should have set the onClick function with the send email function (without invoking it) on the form's opening tag NOT on your submit button. (but the button is still necessary so that it can send the sign that the form needs to be submitted). You also invoked the sendEmail function which is inappropriate and leads to problems.
You must also add event as a parameter in your sendEmail function when creating this function. Then inside the sendEmail function call the event.preventDefault() function .

```
import React from 'react'
import emailjs from 'emailjs-com

class Main extends React.Component {

  constructor(){
    super()
    this.state = {
      fromName:'',
      message:'',
      fromEmail:''
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <article>
          <form method="post" onClick={this.sendEmail} action="#">
            <div className="field half first">
              <label htmlFor="name">Name</label>
              <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value={this.state.fromName} onChange={e => this.setState({fromName: e.target.value})}/>
            </div>
            <div className="field half">
              <label htmlFor="email">Email</label>
              <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value={this.state.fromEmail} onChange={e => this.setState({fromEmail: e.target.value})}/>
            </div>
            <div className="field">
              <label htmlFor="message">Message</label>
              <textarea name="message" id="message" rows="4" value={this.state.message} onChange={e => this.setState({message: e.target.value})}
                placeholder = "..."></textarea>
            </div>
            <ul className="actions">
              <li>
                <input type="submit" value="Send Message" className="special"/>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </form>
        </article>
      </div>
    )
  }

  sendEmail(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const serviceId='...'
    const templateId='...'
    const userId='...'
    emailjs.send(serviceId, templateId, this.state, userId)
    .then((result) => {
        console.log(result.text);
    }, (error) => {
        console.log(error.text);
    });
  }

}

export default Main
```

Comment: Thank you.  I followed your recommendations but I'm getting 'TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'state')' when I press the Send Message button.  The error is in sendEmail when calling emailjs.send

Comment: I refactored the form into a different component and it's all working much better now. thank you

Comment: In your new component did you call sendEmail in the form's opening tag? And also did you use the event preventDefault() function ?  @dulonji

Comment: I did both of those, yes

Comment: Why did you nark my answer as correct? Because it worked correctly ? @dulonji

Comment: Yes, although I moved it to a component it was your changes that helped the problem

Comment: I would recommend you learn to use functional components and the latest hooks